# How to convert html string into string and then append it to the div tag

Tags: jquery

When I click a button the text must be appended aside of the textbox before. I have used the following code but its not working. Can anyone help me out to solve this?

```
$("#plus").click(function() {
    var str = "<input type='text' id='addnum'>";

    $(".textbox1").append($.parseHTML(str));
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vhuvqg6p/1/ - works fine

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vhuvqg6p/2/ - no need to call parseHTML

Comment: share your html also

Comment: is `textbox1` a input element? if so use `$(".textbox1").after(str);` - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vhuvqg6p/3/

Comment: which one is working

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vhuvqg6p/3/

this worked fyn..Thank you

Comment: I have moved the description up because it is always better for the question to be clear before reading the code. I have also removed the *thanks note* as it is not required.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, looks like you are trying to append the new element to an input element which is not valid as input elements cann't have descendants.

Instead you and insert the new element as a sibling of the `.textbox1` element like

```js
$("#plus").click(function() {
  var str = "<input type='text' id='addnum'>";
  $(".textbox1").after(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="textbox1" />
<button id="plus">T</button>
```

Comment: Can we retrieve the values of 2 textbox into an array which are of different id

Comment: @NagaBhavani not clear what you are looking for... can you recreate the issue in the above fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nagabhavani/vhuvqg6p/4/

Once analyse the code in above fiddle..Enter any values in the textbox atleast 2.
After When we click on the button "press" an alert should be arised with both the values in the text box

Comment: @NagaBhavani since we can add more than 1 button use `addnum` as a calss - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vhuvqg6p/5/

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

html code:

```
<input type="text" id="inputtext" />
    <button id="btnclick"></button>
```

JQuery Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnclick').click(function () {
            $("#inputtext").after('<input type="text">');
        });
    });
</script>
```